# How to evaluate the limit $\lim_{y\to 0} (\frac1y)^{\frac1y}$ using l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{y\to 0}  \left(\frac1y\right)^{\frac1y}$$

I tried using the $e^L = g(x)\ln f(x)$ rule but kept getting $\frac \infty  0$ …. how do I solve it?

Comment: Did you mean the limit as $y\to 0$?

Comment: Do you mean that "$e^L=g(x)\log f(x)$ rule" or something of the sort? I guess you mean that to evaluate a limit with $f(x)^{g(x)}$ one looks at $g(x)\log f(x)$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah sorry bout my notation. I just took a test and got pwned by this question... so did the smart guys in my class.. i have to know

Comment: Can you show your work for when you put it in the form $g(x)\ln f(x)$?

Comment: If you let $x=\frac{1}{y}$ then you are looking for $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}  x^x$, which clearly increases without limit

Comment: 1/y * ln(1/y) = (ln1 - lny)/y = (0 - infinity)/0. .........

if i get: infinity/0 = infinity is that still right?

Comment: because technically as y approaches 0 infinity / y = infinity

Comment: When you're getting $\infty\over 0$, Professor l'Hôpital isn't the one you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward approach that you tried works like this. Let $L$ be the desired limit. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\ln L&=\ln\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\frac1y\right)^{1/y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0}\ln\left(\frac1y\right)^{1/y}&&\text{because the log is continuous}\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac1y\ln\frac1y\\
&=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln(1/y)}y\\
&=+\infty\;.
\end{align*}$$

(Note that the limit must actually be the limit as $y\to 0^+$, as otherwise the expression is undefined.) Since $\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac1y=+\infty$, the numerator $\ln(1/y)$ also blows up, just as you discovered, while the denominator approaches $0$ through positive values. In other words, as $y\to 0^+$, the fraction gets bigger and bigger, without any upper bound: its limit is $+\infty$. This should become an automatic response when you see a $\frac{\infty}0$ limit.

Since the log is an increasing function, this means that

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}\left(\frac1y\right)^{1/y}=+\infty$$

as well.

Alternatively, you can substitute $u=\frac1y$: $u\to+\infty$ as $y\to 0^+$, so the limit becomes

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}\left(\frac1y\right)^{1/y}=\lim_{u\to+\infty}u^u\;,$$

which is pretty obviously $+\infty$.

Comment: so I got it right! :D thanks

Comment: @PwnedByEvilTeacher: You’re welcome.